# Is using this sentence correct?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> As a matter of fact, young people are easily influenced by anything; therefore, they could be influenced by such cigarette adverts, then, they will lead unhealthy lives.

Can I say "They will lead unhealthy live." Can I use “lead” without adding “to” after it?

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me the source of the quote

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t pay attention. Anyway, I think it’s from school text book, my cousin send it to me

Answer (score 0):

The use of "lead" is correct.  The future is formed with "will + bare infinitive".

In this sense, "lead" is transitive. The sense with "life" is idiomatic. Examples from [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lead)

> He was able to lead a normal life, despite the illness.

> We certainly don't lead a life of luxury but we're not poor either.

You need to use the singular "a life" or the  plural "lives" and not "live".

Comment: James K, this is te whole context: As a matter of fact, young people are easily influenced by anything; therefore, they could be influenced by such cigarette adverts, then, they will lead unhealthy lives.